# Save default value for empty or missing post meta

Tags: query, post-meta

I am using WordPress and I am using a custom field that has the name `ecpt_carprice` for each post I am publishing, the field is saved in `wp_postmeta` the same as the attached image:

[image]

Some of my cars (posts) do not have a meta key `ecpt_carprice`.
Can you provide me with any means (WordPress/PHP or SQL query) to store for every post without the meta entry a new entry with value 0?

I have this code but I don't know how to use it

```
if ( has_term( '', 'car_brand' )) {

//check if the meta field has a value
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_carprice', true);

if(empty($meta_values)){
//add a default value
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_carprice', '0');
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just react to empty or missing post meta and display 0 instead of cluttering the database with _uninformative_ data?

Comment: @tf is right and you can check the meta_key in the single.php and if empty add the post meta'

Comment: thanks, but i want to query all post, i won't wait to check every single post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to and only need to do what @tf suggested, what is just to take care of displaying a 0 if no value is present, you can construct a function to do so like this:

```
function wpse121165_return_carprice() {
    $ecpt_carprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_carprice', true);
    if(! empty( $ecpt_carprice ) ){
        return $ecpt_carprice;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use the function like this: `echo wpse121165_return_carprice();`

If you really need to update your database, you have to do this another way. Below code should give you an insight on how to do it:

```
 function wpse121165_update_carprice_meta() {
      // args to query for your key
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'ecpt_carprice',
                'value' => 'bogus', // you have to pass a value
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'ecpt_carprice',
                'value' => ''
            )
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids'
      );
      // perform the query to get back an array of ids
      $not_exist_or_empty_ids = new WP_Query( $args );

      foreach ( $not_exist_or_empty_ids as $id ) {
          update_post_meta($id, 'ecpt_carprice', '0');
      }
 }
```

Use the function like this: `wpse121165_update_carprice_meta();`. If you put this in you `functions.php` and perform your meta update on the database, make sure to disable it afterwards and not to call it over and over again.

Comment: thanks @ialocin, but i just have one question, do i should modify this line ?                 'value' => 'bogus', // you have to pass a value
 what is bogus ?

Comment: No, have a look at [WP_Query - Custom_Field_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), there is a bug, which leads to `'compare' => 'NOT EXIST'` requiring a value with it. Bogus is just a english word, google it, you can take any *string* as value, **but** you can not use *null* or a *empty* value. @TayssirCh